# Svn hook script under version control

Tags: svn

In the svn `repository/hooks` directory i have a `pre-commit` script. For now, in the same directory I have also `script.py` that is triggered by `pre-commit`.

In above scenario, my `script.py` is not under version control. That makes sense if I can't trust my users. However, in my case, I can trust my users and for maintenance purposes I would like to keep `script.py` under version control (same repo).

The question is: how to trigger my script: `trunk/tools/script.py` from `repository/hooks/pre-commit` script ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 2 possible solutions (not ideal, though):

a) Checkout `trunk/tools` to `repository/hooks` and write small trampoline:
(not real code, only idea!)

```
svn up tools
python -file tools/script.py %1 %2 %2
exit /b %ERRORLEVEL%
```

b) Cat trunk/tools/script.py to temp file and execute it. (again, idea only, I do not check that arguments passed correctly ...)

```
set TMPFILE=%TEMP%\%RANDOM%.py
svnlook cat %1 -r %2 trunk/tools/script.py > %TMPFILE%
python -file %TMPFILE% %1 %2 %2
exit /b %ERRORLEVEL%
```

P.S. You do not specify OS, so I assume it is Windows.

Comment: Well, I've been wondering about something similar to 2nd solution but it is still ugly hack. For now, let's wait for more answers. Thanks anyway, btw. I use linux.